# Components in RelativeLayout are Squeezed or shrinks in android on resize

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

I have 3 fragments aligned horizontally. I am using Relative layout for 
the last fragment. When I provide an ImageView in the last 
fragment/layout (RelativeLayout) it actually squeeze/shrinks the imageview . But 
when I use LineraLayout it does not. How can I get the same effect in RelativeLayout. ie with out squeezing/shrinking the components. Any help is appreciated

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#58595B">

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imgProfilePhoto"
     android:layout_width="250dp"
     android:layout_height="250dp"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     android:background="@drawable/contact_avatar_default_1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

## Main Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

 <FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/container1"
     android:layout_width="400dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context="com.sample.MainActivity"
     tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />

 <FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/container2"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="#E6E6E6"
     android:layout_weight="90"

     tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />

 <fragment
     android:id="@+id/fragmentContact"
     android:name="com.sample.photoFragment"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     tools:layout="@layout/fragment_photo"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight="10" />
```

Comment: in the first case, is the image cropped and viewed centred with the same original size, and if yes try to add an attribute to the imageView `ScaleType="CentreInside"`

Comment: No, adding scaleType="centerInside" does not make any difference. Its not only a issue to ImageView alone, it happens to VideoView, EditText etc. ie any component added to the Relative Layout cause this issue.

Comment: When does the resize event occur, and by what is it triggered ?

Comment: Post the entire xml code.

Comment: Edited the code with Main Layout

Comment: There is no event for Resize as of now. Please have a look on the Main Layout Code. Container 1 and Container 2 are plain layout file with sizes and weight as seen in the code.

Comment: based on the comments it looks like you need to force the child view's width and height even when its larger than the parent view, this is not the default functionality for android layouts http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:minWidth.  the easiest way of doing it is probably to create a custom view that inherits from RelativeLayout or ViewGroup. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_width="match_parent"` in `ImageView`. Hope this work.

Comment: I was expecting the image should show in 250 x 250 size as shown in the picture

Comment: If you try with match_parent image still squeeze?

Comment: That image should display in the middle of the layout with 250 x 250 size irrespective of the container size. User may drag the parent layout (fragmentContact) to a bigger size in future.